# Home sharing library doesn't show up on iPhone 5 (9.3.2) no matter what I do

Tags: iphone, itunes, music, home-sharing

I'm trying to make my iTunes (12.5.1.21) music library show up in Music on my iPhone 5 (9.3.2). Nothing seems to work, i.e. whatever I try nothing shows up under the My Music tab on my phone (empty view telling me to find some music).

[Apple's instructions to use Home Sharing on iOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202190) are:

> On the screen that appears, tap the category near the middle of the screen. Then tap Home Sharing and choose a shared Library to connect to.

Obviously, there is no such control in the empty view.

Steps taken, with no effect:

- OSX firewall is not enabled.
- Activated Home sharing using the same Apple ID on both iPhone and Mac.
- Updated to latest iTunes (12.5.1.21). Support for iOS 9 was added in version 12.3.0.44.
- Enabled sharing the whole library in iTunes settings (although I'm under the impression that that is a separate feature from home sharing).
- Deauthorized and re-authorized the mac, and reactivated home sharing.
- Restarted iTunes, killed the Music app.
- Restarted mac and phone.
- Logged out of home sharing on phone, waited 15 minutes, logged in again.
- Disabled screen lock and let the phone sit with Music app open.
- Enabled Apple Music in iOS, even though I have no interest in it.
- Restarted router.
- Checked that the required ports aren't blocked in the router, as per Apple troubleshooting instruction, although I fail to see how that would affect things since both my devices are inside the same LAN behind that firewall.
- Confirmed that the itunes remote app for iOS could find itunes.

Are there any magical constraints to Home Sharing they're not telling me?

Comment: You might have to put one song on it to make it work, I'm not sure.

Comment: Yeah maybe, I wouldn't put it past them. If so it would be a pretty ironic misunderstanding of their own feature.